# Why can't I build lighting in UE 5

Tags: build, lighting, unreal-engine5

Ok so first I was adding lights to my game then I noticed there are somehow lights in the building (because I only added a skylight and a directional light and I had a roof photo: https://github.com/7-Bar/error-log/blob/6ac42403a88f87b344da39e4534dfe58a37a2c44/Screenshot%202023-03-19%20at%2016.44.41.png). Then I saw this "lighting needs to be rebuilt error". So I tried to do that. But then I got a "lighting build failed" and "map check found some errors"[image]

I tried restarting my computer, updating unreal engine 5.1 to 5.11, and it still does not work.
output logs:
https://github.com/7-Bar/error-log/blob/main/log